# Two Way Embedding vs. One Way Embedding in MongoDB (Many-To-Many)

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql

I would like to discuss with you, if it makes any sense to use two way embedding instead of one way embedding, when modeling an N:M relationship in MongoDB.

Let's say, we have two entities: A **Product** can belong to many (few) **Categories**, and a **Category** can have many (lots of) **Products**.

## Two Way Embedding

If we use this approach, our **categories** would look like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Baby",
  products: [2]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Electronics",
  products: [1, 2]
}
```

And **products**:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "HDMI Cable",
  categories: [2]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Babyphone",
  categories: [1, 2]
}
```

#### Queries:

If we would like to fetch products that belong to a specific category:

```js
const category = categoriesCollection.findOne({name: "Electronics"});
const products = productsCollection.find({_id: {$in: category.products}}).toArray();
```

If we would like to fetch categories that belong to a specific product:

```js
const product = productsCollection.findOne({name: "Babyphone"});
const categories = categoriesCollection.find({_id: {$in: product.categories}}).toArray();
```

## One Way Embedding

Because a product will probably only belong to two or three categories, but a category can have millions of products, I would embed the categories into the products, not the other way round. So we can be sure that we'll never reach the 16 MB maximum document size.

Our products will look the same as above, but categories won't have a "products"-field any longer.

If we would like to fetch categories for a specific product, our query stays the same as above:

```js
const product = productsCollection.findOne({name: "Babyphone"});
const categories = categoriesCollection.find({_id: {$in: product.categories}}).toArray();
```

The other way round, if we fetch products for a specific category, our query changes to this:

```js
const category = categoriesCollection.findOne({name: "Electronics"});
const products = productsCollection.find({categories: category._id}).toArray();
```

In our products collection, we put a (multikey) **index** on the categories-array, so performance should be okay.

## My conclusion

One-way-embedding seems to be the better solution to me, as we won't reach maximum document size, while not having any(?) disadvantages in relation to the two-way-embedding approach. Why would anyone ever want to do two-way-embedding? Am I missing something? Performance-wise, it should be almost the same, or no?

What do you think?

Comment: Actually there is another option without embedding at all, a third collection where you keep only productId and categoryId. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59583812/11717458), I give an example for many to many relation. If it helps you, you can upvote my answer there.

Comment: @SuleymanSah This way we would just mimic a RDBMS, wouldn't we? In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582640/need-advice-to-design-database-in-mongodb-with-mongoose/59583812#59583812) you wrote this code:

´const result = await Patient.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: "examinations",
    populate: {
      path: "hospitalId"
    }
  });´

This would result in 3 requests to the database (each populate() adds one), whereas with embedding, we only need two requests, so embedding would perform better. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Adam for that part we can use aggregation to make only one db access, the real advantage is when we add, update or delete a relation, only one operation, with a simple code.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes, with using $lookup instead of Mongoose populate(), we can get a "real" join, so we only need one request. But then we face another issue: What we receive from the aggregation is no longer a Patient model object, and we would have to define some Output model in Mongoose, that fits. So all in all, that doesn't feel easier to me at all. Also, create, update or delete isn't too complicated if we just embed the ObjectId?

Comment: No need to define a mongoose model for the response of aggregation. We can return the result to the client.