# REST API to update MongoDB many to many relationship

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, schema

We have a two mongodb models with many to many relationships - **Images** and **Articles**.

An image can be used in any article, and an article can have any images.  From the UI perspective, the user will want to see two views

1. Article view - the article and the images used in the article
2. Image view - the image and all the articles that the image was used in.

For this reason, I am considering doing two way references with the id's.

Example schema:

Images

```
_id: ObjectId(''),
url: '',
description: 'some description',
keywords: ['some', keywords']
articles: [] // array of references to image id's
```

Articles

```
_id: ObjectId(''),
body: 'text body',
title: 'some title',
images: [] // array of references to image id's
```

My question is this as follows.

I have to design a REST API to establish the relationships.
For example

```
POST /articles/{id}/images // add an image to an article
```

In the application code for the above API, if I were to update both the `image` and the `article` documents, I would have to use transactions.  Is this design ok?

The other options I can think of are

1. Have the client call two API's (the other being linking an article to an image)
2. Use a message bus to notify images that an article has used it, and have the application handle it updating the `image` document.
3. Have a third model to handle the linking.  I.e. a `Usages` collection

I can't think of any other options, or what's the best practice.  Many mongodb schema design tutorials talk about two way referencing, but do not mention how it is handled from the perspective of API design.

Comment: I don't like two way referencing because  it requires two operations when inserting and deleting which must be done in a transactional way. Third option with linking with an additional collection seems cleaner. If you are interested in a mongoose solution, you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582640/need-advice-to-design-database-in-mongodb-with-mongoose/59583812#59583812)

Comment: @SuleymanSah Would you design the API around the third collection as the resource?  Or use have either / both images or articles resource API update the this third collection?

Comment: Hmm, good question, I think both are possible and fine, but I would go with second option.