# Storing Notification with MongoDB (along with read status)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is this an efficient way of storing notifications with MongoDB. I want to keep track of past notifications and if the notification has been read by the user.

```
NotificationSchema: {
   title: {type: String, required: true},
   context: {type: String, required: true},
   createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), required: true},
   readBy: [
      userObjectID: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
      readAt: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now()}
   ]
}
```

My worry is that when the list gets big, each user would have to go through the entire "readBy" field in order to determine if the user has read it.

Should I also store within the UserSchema, a field to record all notifications read by the user?

Thank you! Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider to create an additional intermediate model like UserNotification, and remove the readBy array field from Notification.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  context: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now(), required: true }
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true }
});

const UserNotificationSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  notification: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Notification"
  },
  readAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now() }
});

module.exports = {
  Notification: mongoose.model("Notification", NotificationSchema),
  User: mongoose.model("User", UserSchema),
  UserNotification: mongoose.model("UserNotification", UserNotificationSchema)
};
```

With this design, adding a UserNotification requires only a simple insert into only one collection, and our Notification and User schema is not polluted.

But we need to setup [virtual populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) on the Notification and User schemas to be able to reference UserNotification. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582640/need-advice-to-design-database-in-mongodb-with-mongoose/59583812#59583812) answer for an example how to setup virtual populate.

Comment: Good design, how would you go about it, if for example, you're to send notifications to all users in the DB? Thanks