# MongoDB way of doing many-to-many relationships

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I know there's a few answered questions that ask the same exact thing, but I'm not satisfied with the answer.

I have two models: `User` and `Club`

- a `User` can "own" multiple clubs
- a `Club` can "beOwned" by multiple users
- it's routine that a club needs to query for all its owners and a user needs to query for all their clubs

So it's a many-to-many relationship. I currently have an `ownedClubs` ObjectID array in the `User` model and an `owners` ObjectID array in the `Club` model, but I don't think that's the best way to do it, because there are now two places that the "owned-owner" relationship has to be synchronized, and if it ever gets out of sync ([Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)), it may be difficult to fix/catch.

If I were solving this problem in a relational database, there would be a reference table linking owners to clubs and both models would just query the table, but there must be a more Mongo-y way of doing this.

Comment: I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59583812/11717458) which may help you.

Comment: How many _clubs_ and _users_ are likely to be stored in this model? How many clubs per user, and also how many users per club? Modeling depends upon these numbers - with respect to MongoDB's document structure.

Comment: @prasad_ 10,000+ users, 50+ clubs. About 1-3 owners per club though

Comment: @SuleymanSah your answer is just what i was looking for! Thanks!