# How to store id's on two collections like many-many relation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got two collections. Cases and persons. Is it good to do it in this way? I mean, both collections store id of each other in arrays. So if i add new person to case i also add new case to person collection.

```
const CaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "Tutaj wpisz treść raportu"
    },
    persons: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Person
    }]

})

const PersonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
   cases: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Cases
}]
})
```

Comment: It's generally considered harder to keep two things in sync, so often times there's a 3rd table that links people to cases in a M:M relationship.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And then can i use populate() on it? Or it's a bad idea and i should get both objects in separate functions?

Comment: Can you check this answer? It shows you how to populate when using many to many relation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59583812/11717458